# Permissions to change only directory content and not itself

Tags: permissions, directory

We have a directory and want to protect that from remove and rename, but we need to be able to rename, remove and create contents. What we can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permission to remove and rename a directory is determined by its parent's permissions, not its own (just like other files). Just set the permissions on the directory to what you need and make its parent `-w`.

Depending on your use case you may want to make the directory sticky `+t` as well - then users can't move around others' files, only their own.

Comment: Thanks. But how we can't remove `~` directory but we can create new files and remove files inside it?

Comment: If `/home` is owned by root and `rwxr-xr-x`, and `/home/ali` is owned by `ali` and `rwx------` then `ali` can create, rename, and delete files in `/home/ali`, but only root can delete or rename `/home/ali` itself, because doing that needs write access to `/home`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is not possible with standard Linux technology. You need RichACLs to configure precisely that.

If the side effects are not a problem then you can remove write permissions from the parent directory.

OK, I have to correct my first thought: There is a work-around with standard features. You can move that directory to a different path, create an empty directory with the same name and without any write permissions in its place and make a `mount --bind` from the new position to the old one. Active mount points cannot be deleted but the content permissions are not affected.

Comment: Interesting bending of the feature mount :-D

Comment: In general, there is no reason to move an answer if the question is closed as a dupe. You can do so, of course, but it's up to you. Since your answer does provide a neat workaround, I'll merge the questions.

Comment: @terdon How can I move an answer? Or do you mean I could copy it to the other question? I thought that the "original" question gets more attention (because dupes are not shown in the search, are they?); that would be reason enough for me to put the answers there.

Comment: By move, I meant delete and repost to the duplicate. However, dupes are most certainly shown in the search which is part of the reason why it is rarely needed to repost answers. Many duplicates act as signposts to the master Q&A so they get a lot of views. You also still get rep for votes on answers on closed posts.