# How to make a directory really undeletable?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod, delete

I'm using this commands to make `DIRECTORY` undeletable:

- `sudo chmod 000 DIRECTORY`
- `sudo chattr +i DIRECTORY`

But I can delete it using this commands:

- `sudo chattr -i DIRECTORY`
- `sudo rm -rf DIRECTORY`

How can I make `DIRECTORY` really undeletable?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151727/117549

Comment: A directory on a CDROM can't be deleted except by destroying the filesystem on that CDROM. You could also create the directory on a USB thumbdrive with a read-write switch, set the switch to read-only, then break the switch (of course, nothing resists a determined person with a soldering iron). If you want to accomplish it in software, you have to modify the filesystem code, but I am not sure if the resulting filesystem is still POSIX compliant. You can also mount a filesystem read-only or make a logical volume read-only, but this can easily be reversed.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you need to make a directory "really undeletable"? I have the feeling that this is not your real problem.

Comment: @berndbausch I want to know is it possible to do that or not.

Comment: In general, you don't often find entities that can be created but cannot be deleted.

Comment: I am confident it is not possible if you want to use unmodified system software. It is possible using the means I outlined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have access to the root user who can write to your partition, you cannot make anything undeleteable as you still can `cat /dev/zero > /dev/partition` and destroy all the data.

Ways to mitigate that for certain:

- Read only media: CD/DVD/BD-Ray (tends to degrade over time, most off the shelf optical disks become unreadable sooner or later unless you store them in a very special environment)
- Media with read only switch (can also die over time)
- Paper (yeah, you can print something valuable and it becomes sort of undeleteable)
- No root access

And everything can still be physically destroyed.